# How to not allow override description fields of a product for a specific language using webservice?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I try to sync some products between two prestashop websites using webservice. For example the description of a product from the destination website should be the same as the description of the product from source website after synchronization.

Both websites(source and destination) are multi-languages.
Source website has English and French languages, the destination website has English(id=4), French(id=5) and Spanish(id=6) languages.

The problem is that existing description for Spanish language from destination website is overridden with blank text after sync. The same issue is for the other fields: short description, meta description, meta title. Interesting is the text for `link_rewrite` field is kept for Spanish language.

Here is a part of the XML which is SENT with webservice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<product>
  <id>8224</id>
  <description>
    <language id="4">English text</language>
    <language id="5">Franch text</language>
  </description>
</product>
</prestashop>
```

I want to keep the existing description from Spanish language even if I don't send the text for it on XML.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to retrieve the existing object, and only update the language you are interested in updating.

**Here's an example of updating a product name only in one language**

```
<?php

include(__DIR__.'/config/config.inc.php');
include(__DIR__.'/init.php');
include(__DIR__.'/PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

/* Connect to the PrestaShop Web-service */
define('PS_SHOP_URL', 'http://localhost/prestashop');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'YOURKEYHERE');
$ws = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_URL, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, false);

/* Retrieve the existing product (Product ID = 1) */
$xml = $ws->get(['url' => PS_SHOP_URL.'/api/products/1']);
echo 'Before: <pre>';
print_r($xml->product->name->language);
echo '</pre>';

/* Update only the name in French */
$xml->product->name->language[1] = 'New Name';
unset($xml->product->manufacturer_name, $xml->product->quantity, $xml->product->position_in_category); /* Removing fields which are not writeable */
$result = $ws->edit(['resource' => 'products', 'id' => 1, 'putXml' => $xml->asXML()]);

/* Check new values */
$xml = $ws->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_URL.'/api/products/1'));
echo 'After: <pre>';
print_r($xml->product->name->language);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Result/Output**

```
Before:

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [0] => Hummingbird printed t-shirt
    [1] => Hummingbird printed t-shirt
)

After:

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [0] => Hummingbird printed t-shirt
    [1] => New Name
)
```

The PSWebServiceLibrary.php file can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/PSWebServiceLibrary.php

And you can find more example of using the PrestaShop web-service here:

- For PrestaShop 1.6.x: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+one-page+documentation
- For PrestaShop 1.7.x: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/webservice/tutorials/prestashop-webservice-lib/

I hope this helps!